# Update column values based on equal values in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench:

Starting point:

| ParcelID | Address |
| --- | --- |
| 44 | street xxxx |
| 32 | street yyyy |
| 44 | empty |
| 44 | null |
| 12 | empty |
| 12 | street zzzz |

What should be:

| ParcelID | Address |
| --- | --- |
| 44 | street xxxx |
| 32 | street yyyy |
| 44 | street xxxx |
| 44 | street xxxx |
| 12 | street zzzz |
| 12 | street zzzz |

Basically, I want to populate that same column of the same table if they have the same ParcelID. I read around that with a self join I could solve the problem, so far I've written this: any help?

```
UPDATE table t1 
INNER JOIN table t2  ON t1.ParcelID = t2.ParcelID
SET t1.Address = IF(t2.Address = '' OR NULL, t2.Address, t1.Address)
WHERE t1.ParcelID = t2.ParcelID;
```

any suggestions? Is writing the WHERE clause redundant?

Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be moving the condition inside the join and set address2 to address1 directly, as done followingly:

```
UPDATE     tab t1
INNER JOIN tab t2
        ON t1.ParcelID = t2.ParcelID
       AND (t1.Address = '' OR t1.Address IS NULL)
       AND NOT (t2.Address = '' OR t2.Address IS NULL)
SET t1.Address = t2.Address;
```

Demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w993cnRZKXk4632dsoT9H4/0).